# Недоступность поддоменов с произвольным именем

Tags: nginx, dns, laravel, поддомены

Не могу настроить поддомены на nginx.

Использую конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.php;

    server_name  _;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/laravel/error.log;

    rewrite_log     on;

    root /var/www/main/public;

    location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
        expires 30d;
        log_not_found off;
    }


    location ~* \.(js|css|ico)$ {
        expires 3h;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;    
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Когда я подключаюсь к `subdomain.example.com`, пишет, что веб-страница недоступна, и в логе `/var/log/nginx/laravel/access.log` отображается подобная строка:

> [23/Jun/2015:07:06:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.125 Safari/537.36"

`Route` тоже настроен на любой поддомен:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.example.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($sub) {
        return $sub;
    }); 
});
```

Что я делаю не так?

Сайт находится не на локальной машине.

Comment: а что возвращает `wget -S --spider http://subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вот:
 --2015-06-23 13:28:39--  http://subdomain.example.com/
Resolving subdomain.example.com (subdomain.example.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'subdomain.example.com'

Comment: ну, это вообще-то был адрес из вашего примера. надо было подставить актуальное имя.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я подставил, просто не хотел свой светить, поэтому заменил. если нужно, то вот artie.ml и вот выход 

`Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-06-23 08:41:01--  http://test.artie.ml/
Resolving test.artie.ml (test.artie.ml)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'test.artie.ml'`

Comment: извините, что слишком плохо о вас подумал. имя субдомена не резолвится. если оно вам нужно только для тестов с локального компьютера, то впишите его в /etc/hosts (или аналог этого файла в вашей операционной системе). если нужно постоянно — то добавьте соответствующую dns-запись в описание вашего домена.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но мне нужно, чтобы заработали любые поддомены, автоматически.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25097/discussion-between-artie-lay-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как выяснилось, проблема была в том, что не резолвились в *ip*-адрес сервера имена вида `произвольный_поддомен.домен.ком`.

чтобы этого добиться, в описании домена `домен.ком` надо добавить так называемую *wildcard*-запись. например, так:

```
* IN A ip-адрес-сервера
```